# Sending and receiving strings over a TCP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send

So, I was trying to send data between clients and server using socket programming in C++. Now, I read an answer in StackOverflow, where it mentioned we have to check how much of our original msg is received each time we send it, and then wait until we get the information completely. To do that, I used the following sendMsg() and receive() function.

```
string receive()
    {
        string msg = "";
        char last_character = '%';
        do
        {
            char buffer[2048] = {0};
            read(sockfd, buffer, 2048);
            string s(buffer);
            msg += s;
            last_character = s[s.size() - 1];
        } while (last_character != '|');
        return msg.substr(0, msg.size() - 1);
    }
    bool sendMsg(string s)
    {
        s += '|';
        char buffer[s.size()];
        strcpy(buffer, &s[0]);
        int bytes_total = 0;
        int bytes_left = s.length();
        int bytes_now = 0;
        while (bytes_left > 0)
        {
            bytes_now = send(sockfd, &buffer[bytes_total], bytes_left, 0);
            if (bytes_now == -1)
            {
                err("Error sending message");
                return false;
            }
            assert(bytes_now <= bytes_left);
            bytes_left -= bytes_now;
            bytes_total += bytes_now;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This works fine for the most part except, it sometimes adds a '|' character, i.e. the delimiter character before the message. This issue is prominent just when I connect a new client to the server and I try to send some message to the client to print in it's console. It's something like this:

```
    usernames[username] = client_socket;
    comm.sendMsg(string(GRN) + "Username accepted.\n" + string(NRM));
    cout << GRN << username << " connected." << NRM << endl;
    comm.sendMsg(readme(username));
```

where, the usernames is an unordered_map which stores the client_socket for each unique username, and the readme function is just a string like "Welcome to the chatroom, " + username. Here, #define NRM  "\x1B[0m", #define GRN  "\x1B[32m"

So, the output I get sometimes is

```
Enter the IP address of the server: l
Connected to server.
Enter your username: user
Username accepted.
|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            |
|   [server]: Welcome to the chatroom, user                  |
|                                                            |
|   [server]: Here are the commands you can use:             |
|                                                            |
|   1. status             : Lists the status of all users    |
|   2. connect [username] : Connect to username to start     |
|                           chatting                         |
|   3. goodbye            : Ends current chatting session    |
|   4. close              : Disconnects the user from the    |
|                           server                           |
|   5. clear              : Clears the chat from the window  |
|   6. Ctrl + C (client)  : Disconnects the client and       |
|                           terminates its chat session      |
|                           if present                       |
|   7. Ctrl + C (server)  : Terminates the server and all the|
|                           clients connected to the server  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can notice the | just after the Username accepted line, which is unnecessary. I am not able to figure out the issue. Is there some issue with the sendMsg and receive function? Or that is fine, I have to look into the rest of the code. The client and the server files are close to 700 lines of C++ code, so I didn't post here directly.

EDIT:
I changed the received function as follows:

```
string receive()
    {
        string msg = "";
        char last_character = '%';
        while (last_character != '|')
        {
            char buffer[2048] = {0};
            int bytes_read = read(sockfd, buffer, 2048);
            if (bytes_read <= 0)
            {
                err("Error receiving message");
                return "";
            }
            string s(buffer, bytes_read);
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size() - 1; i++)
                if (s[i] == '|')
                {
                    s.erase(s.begin() + i);
                }
            msg += s;
            last_character = s[s.size() - 1];
        }
        return msg.substr(0, msg.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: 1: You should rethink `char buffer[s.size()];` since standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. Why use a `char` buffer anyway? Just use a `std::string` and read directly into that

Comment: 2: `read(sockfd, buffer, 2048);` - you need to capture how many characters you read too and adjust what you add to your `std::string` accordingly

Comment: Note: TCP is a streaming protocol; It will buffer many sends into one packet, fragment sends across multiple packets, or do whatever makes the most sense to move the data as fast as possible with minimal overhead. That means `read(sockfd, buffer, 2048);` without capturing and consulting the return value  is suicide. You have no way to know how much data you'll get other than it won't be more than 2048 bytes.

Comment: TCP/IP is a stream protocol not a messaging protocol. So `read` will read any amount of available data up to the your maximum buffer size. This might be anywhere between a faction of a sent message up to many messages end-to-end.  There might be fragments of the next message in the buffer which you need to preserve and include in the next whole message read.

Comment: Your code isn't caring how many bytes it received; `s` can contain all the received bytes and then some extra. If a 0 byte is received then s doesn't contain all the received bytes.

Comment: Note: you are not sending the string's terminating null, so `string s(buffer);` will not know when to stop reading `buffer` into `s`. This can be solved by making use of the return value from `read` to tell the program when to stop reading, but you still need to make sure you got the whole string, and this typically means you either read the stream byte-by-byte looking for a terminator or inserting the size of the string into the stream (in an integer of known length and byte order) ahead of the string and loop, similar to your send loop, until you got everything.

Comment: @user4581301 I changed the receive function. Does this make any difference? I am still getting the issue of | being present before some messages.

Comment: You're still missing the fact that TCP does not respect your messages one bit. That `'|'` may not be the last character in a packet. It could be right at the start. It could be somewhere in the middle. You'll have to grab data from the stream and look for the `'|'` the hard way to know when you've found the end of the message

Comment: @user4581301 I edited the answer. Is this correct? Like now, my problem seems to be solved. But, I am not sure if this is the correct approach could you kindly check it.

Comment: @user4581301 While running my code, I saw that sometimes the Welcome to the chatroom thing is not printing after the username is accepted msg for some of the clients. This thing is also rare but, I am not sure about the issue.

Comment: You don't want to lose parts of other messages, and because you may read more than one message and return return only one message, you risk losing data. Try the other way around. Scan through the `char` array. If a character in the array is not `'|'`, add it to the `string`. If a character is `'|'`, you have completed message. Call a function  to process the `string` and pass it the `string`. When the processing function returns, the reading loop starts where it left off, reading until the end of the array. When it reaches the end of the array, it reads the socket again to refill the array.

Comment: @user4581301 From reading your input, I though of a way like this. So, when I encounter a '|' I should call a function, which say inserts the string into a queue. Then, I change the variable msg = "", as this will be the start of the new string. Then I read the things from the queue in order. I have to make the receive function void, then. And then check the queue it seems. This looks like it will work. But, it seems too cumbersome to do things this way. Is there any different way? Also, can you suggest any good resources for this. This assignment is very basic but I am still struggling.

Comment: If you have to separate messages by delimiter, it's about the best you can do.  There's room for improvements like only bulk-updating the `string` when you're at the end of one read's worth of data or when you find the delimiter. If you're stuck looking for a delimiter, you gotta look for the delimiter. That said...

Comment: My preference is to prepend strings with the length of the string in an integer of known byte-order and length and forgo delimiters. This takes up a couple extra bytes of transmitted data unless you can guarantee that all of your strings will always be less than 256 characters long. This turns into write length, write length bytes into the socket  on the sender side and receive length, size `string` to hold length, and receive length bytes directly into `string` at the receiver. You still have to loop all of the sends and reads in case they stop part way through...

Comment: ..., but it's about as efficient as you get. That said, efficiency's usually not the problem at this level. It takes MUCH longer to move the data that it does to read itr even when you use all but the most inefficient reading methods. You probably won't see the difference between fast and fast enough over the slowness of trans mission.

Answer (score 0):

```
comm.sendMsg(string(GRN) + "Username accepted.\n" + string(NRM));
```

This is going to write one string followed by a trailing `|` to the socket.

```
comm.sendMsg(readme(username));
```

Immediately afterwards this is going to write a second such string.

```
read(sockfd, buffer, 2048);
```

The expectation of this logic here is that this will read, at most, a single message, perhaps partially.

This expectation is flawed.

If, for whatever reason, the server didn't get around to `read()`ing the socket until the sender wrote ***both*** messages to it, this will read both messages into `buffer`, and the shown code will be blissfully unaware it.

This logical bug needs to be fixed, before any further debugging takes place, as this logical bug makes all subsequent observations worthless.

```
        char buffer[s.size()];
        strcpy(buffer, &s[0]);
```

As an aside: the above is completely not needed. `s.c_str()`, together with `s.size()`, gives you everything that's needed to `write()` the string. No separate `char` buffer is required.